# UK resident selling a house in Italy

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, italy

I purchased a house in Italy for €250,000 in 2014. At the time, I was a student in the UK, and I didn't officially transfer my residency to the UK. I  now (2023) work and live in the UK (and I've been a UK citizen since 2022) and moved my residency here. I want to sell the house, which is now estimated to be worth around €450,000. Do I have to pay a 28% capital gain tax to HMRC? Are there ways to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the UK has any formal concept of moving residency. Tax laws around residency are complicated but probably if you've been in the UK for more than half of each tax year HMRC would consider you were resident.

In any case Capital Gains Tax appears to be charged based on your current status so short of moving away from the UK for at least several months and perhaps [five years](https://www.gov.uk/tax-return-uk#if-you-return-to-the-uk-within-5-years), you are going to be liable for it.